# How did they get the baby actor in Tootsie to repeatedly turn its head away from food?

Tags: film-techniques, tootsie

In Tootsie, they have a scene where the baby keeps turning it's head away as a spoon is brought close to it's mouth. Usually the only role for a baby in a movie is crying but this seems more complex so I don't know how it was done. Can someone suggest any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they hired a kid which do that normally...!

Comment: Probably off camera sweets or shinies.

Comment: Put food on the spoon that the baby doesn't like... try to feed it when it's not hungry... Any number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Hoffman successfully fed the baby at least once, per the publicity still below, apparently from deleted/unused footage.

[image]

Since the baby refusing food wasn't in [the screenplay](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Tootsie.pdf) which just says...

> Dorothy feeding Amy applesauce (they are both covered with it). Amy still cries.

...we can reasonably assume that they just filmed him feeding the young 'un for a half-hour or so, then used the best footage, which included the head-turning. It doesn't take much for a baby to become distracted by the bright lights and film crew.